# Does hibernate add a index on table creation by default (mysql)

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.5 with mysql 5.1, and use "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" = create to create the tables. When I run the command on my tables:

`show index from user;`

I can see index being created . Does hibernate add these by default, as I have not added any index in my class annotations or hibernate config.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.

Comment: It's maybe just mysql (PRIMARY KEYs are always indexed, for example. FOREIGN KEYs also, but just on INNODB). If you have indexes on other fields, than it may come from hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Raphael, I found the answer. Yes, MYSQL indexes the PRIMARY and FOREIGN keys by default when using INNODB. Hibernate does not do that by default to answer the question.